# Have WINE installed - would like to install and run Coreldraw9 from cd. Possible?

Tags: 14.04

Have WINE installed - would like to install from cd and run Coreldraw9 from ubuntu laptop. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but have you considered using a newer program? CorelDRAW9 was released in late August 1999 and is almost 16 years old!

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) is free, modern, and works well in Ubuntu, it may be a slight learning curve from what you are used to, but it is better to learn something modern and up to date!

If you don't like it there is [Krita](https://krita.org/), or if you are actually trying to touch up or edit photos there is [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/). You may be able to get the program running in WINE but it is not a long term solution, the program pre-dates any modern operating system. You may get it running now, but with each newer operating system the chances of it working decrease, while the features in modern (free) software just keep on getting better.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WINE Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=1095) you should be able to just install and use CorelDRAW 9 by inserting the CD and running the `SETUP.EXE` file. Beware however that, at least under WINE 1.6, cut-and-paste isn't working correctly. If your affected by that issue I'd suggest, based on the comments, to try and run `winetricks dcom98 mfc42` in a Terminal window after you've installed and tested CorelDRAW and see if the issue can be "fixed" this way.

Whether it works or not: Please write short review and add it to the WINE application compatibility database so that other users can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Please upvote and mark as accepted answer if this helped you or ask for clarification if it didn't. As I don't actually own any Corel software my ability to help is somewhat limited through.